# Error mounting /dev/sdb2 at /media

Tags: linux, automounting, error-handling

The address could not be accessed. I'm trying to mount the disk, but I can't because of an error

[image]

Comment: Is there more information in the system log? What does `gdisk -l /dev/sdb` show?

Comment: Post the output of $lsblk -f

Comment: @Grigorios - surely it's `lsblk` not `$lsblk`

Comment: Thank you! How could I miss this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.